# self.method (params) Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie and I would like to know if is it possible to define model methods with params. I mean. I have this method to calculate distances using spherical coordinates

```
#in my model

#Haversin formula to calculate distance between spherical coordinates 
def self.distance(b)                                                
  rad_per_deg = Math::PI/180  # PI / 180                                                      
  rkm = 6371                  # Earth radius in kilometers                                    
  #rm = rkm * 1000            # Radius in meters                                              
  a=[]                                                                                        
  a.push(self.lat)                                                                            
  a.spuh(self.long)                                                                           

  dlon_rad = (b[1]-a[1]) * rad_per_deg  # Delta, converted to rad                             
  dlat_rad = (b[0]-a[0]) * rad_per_deg                                                        

  lat1_rad, lon1_rad = a.map! {|i| i * rad_per_deg }                                          
  lat2_rad, lon2_rad = b.map! {|i| i * rad_per_deg }                                          

  a = Math.sin(dlat_rad/2)**2 + Math.cos(lat1_rad) * Math.cos(lat2_rad) * Math.sin(dlon_rad/2)**2

  c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))                                                             

  distance=rkm * c                                                                            
  return distance                                                                             
end
```

I want this to work like: obj.distance(b) where b is an array of latitude and longitude. But when I try this on irb I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `distance' for #<Object:0x000000058854c8>
```

Probably I'm missing something.

```
class Meteo < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                
  attr_accessible :date, :humidity, :lat, :long, :pressure, :temp, :town, :wind, :wind_direction
, :rain_quantity                                                                                

  #Haversin formula to calculate distance between spheric coordinates                           
  def self.distance(b)                                                                          
    rad_per_deg = Math::PI/180  # PI / 180                                                      
    rkm = 6371                  # Earth radius in kilometers                                    
    #rm = rkm * 1000            # Radius in meters                                              
    a=[]                                                                                        
    a.push(self.lat)                                                                            
    a.spuh(self.long)                                                                           

    dlon_rad = (b[1]-a[1]) * rad_per_deg  # Delta, converted to rad                             
    dlat_rad = (b[0]-a[0]) * rad_per_deg                                                        

    lat1_rad, lon1_rad = a.map! {|i| i * rad_per_deg }                                          
    lat2_rad, lon2_rad = b.map! {|i| i * rad_per_deg }                                          

    a = Math.sin(dlat_rad/2)**2 + Math.cos(lat1_rad) * Math.cos(lat2_rad) * Math.sin(dlon_rad/2)
**2                                                                                             
    c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))                                                             

    distance=rkm * c                                                                            
    return distance                                                                             
  end                                                                                           
end
```

And I call this on irb like:

irb> m=Meteo.last

irb> b=[86.43971008189519, 23.477053751481986]

irb> m.distance(b)

Comment: It is a class method How can you access it as an instance method as you told `obj.distance(b)` ? you can access it by only `YourClass.distance(b)` or you can make it as an instance method by `def distance(b)` not `def self.distance(b)`

Comment: `a.spuh(self.long)` should probably be `a.push(self.long)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove `self`.

When you write `def self.distance`, you mean that the method will be called on the model class. You should use `def distance` if you want the method to be called on a model instance.

Compare:

```
class SomeModel
  def self.distance
    # ...
  end
end

SomeModel.distance
```

With:

```
class SomeModel
  def distance
    # ...
  end
end

obj = SomeModel.new
obj.distance
```

Comment: OMG You are right!! Thanks a lot! Now it works. I know: newbie and stupid questions. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, you are defining a class method (with `def self.distance`) but are calling it on an instance of that class (`obj.distance(array)`).

You should call the method on obj's class e.g. `Meteo.distance(array)`.
Or simply define it as an instance method, by just leaving the `self` in method definition.

Hope, that helps